# Does SQLite.net .FirstOrDefault first return every row and then query those with a where?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

If I have a statement like this:

```
return _sqlconnection.Table<Student>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
```

Will the first retrieve all the Students and then select through then to find where the Id matches or will it know to send a SQL statement to the database with a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3):

In SQLite.Net PCL it looks like FirstOrDefault() gets converted to a limit 1 query. However, in your case you are applying a predicate to the FirstOrDefault. That would cause the entire table to get loaded since SQLite.Net doesn't handle complex Linq very gracefully.

If you want to make sure the whole table is **not** loaded, go for something like this:

```
return _sqlconnection.Table<Student>().Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

There's a [good thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11883/is-sqlite-net-table-method-loading-the-entire-table-into-a-collection) in the Xamarin forums about this topic.